# Cargo `OUT_DIR` env var not found when run a specific test

Tags: rust, integration-testing, rust-cargo

Can someone help me to understand this?

I have a [rust project](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/goofy-curran-xnkvyt?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00063b6jowgmjwb3%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B66.87906371911573%252C33.120936280884266%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00023b6jzjcscvm3%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00043b6j3hs9amj9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00053b6jecni5xtl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpr1992e00023b6jzjcscvm3%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00023b6jzjcscvm3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clpr1992e00053b6jecni5xtl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00053b6jecni5xtl%2522%257D%252C%2522clpr1992e00043b6j3hs9amj9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00043b6j3hs9amj9%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpr1bxhi008s3b6jq2qm6wub%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1bxhi008s3b6jq2qm6wub%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clpr1bxn800ldeeex763z3yfy%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) that has a lib crate: `my_crate_2`. Here is the file structure of it:

```
my_project/
├── Cargo.toml
└── src/
    └── main.rs
my_crate_2/
├── Cargo.toml
|-- build.rs
└── src/
    └── lib.rs
|__ tests/ 
    |__my_crate_2.rs
```

In `my_crate_2/tests/my_crate_2.rs` are my integration tests.

In the integration tests, I want to extract the env var `OUT_DIR` in them. [According to the cargo doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html), `OUT_DIR` should be set by `Cargo`.

A trivial test:

```
#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests {
    use my_crate_2::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_add() {
        // I need to use env var `OUT_DIR` here
        // err: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NotPresent
        // note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
        let out_dir = std::env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
        println!("OUT_DIR is {}", out_dir);

        assert_eq!(add(2, 5), 7);
    }
}
```

I ran all the integration tests with `cargo test -- --nocapture` in the `my_crate_2/` dir, and the test passed (`OUT_DIR` existed).

```
cargo test -- --nocapture
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/my_crate_2-e7e58afb09a93b31)

running 1 test
test tests::it_works ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

     Running tests/my_crate_2.rs (target/debug/deps/my_crate_2-9892d21b51d30121)

running 1 test
OUT_DIR is /workspaces/workspace/my_crate_2/target/debug/build/my_crate_2-443e542c04636da9/out
test tests::test_add ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

   Doc-tests my_crate_2

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

But if I only run a specific test: `cargo test --package my_crate_2 --test my_crate_2 -- tests::test_add --nocapture`, the test would fail with `OUT_DIR` env var not found.

```
cargo test --package my_crate_2 --test my_crate_2 -- tests::test_add --nocapture
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running tests/my_crate_2.rs (target/debug/deps/my_crate_2-9892d21b51d30121)

running 1 test
thread 'tests::test_add' panicked at tests/my_crate_2.rs:10:48:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NotPresent
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
test tests::test_add ... FAILED
```

Can anyone help me to understand why `OUT_DIR` is not set by Cargo when targeting a single test? And how should I fix it?

I created a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/goofy-curran-xnkvyt?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00063b6jowgmjwb3%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B66.87906371911573%252C33.120936280884266%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00023b6jzjcscvm3%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00043b6j3hs9amj9%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00053b6jecni5xtl%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpr1992e00023b6jzjcscvm3%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00023b6jzjcscvm3%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clpr1992e00053b6jecni5xtl%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00053b6jecni5xtl%2522%257D%252C%2522clpr1992e00043b6j3hs9amj9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1992e00043b6j3hs9amj9%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpr1bxhi008s3b6jq2qm6wub%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpr1bxhi008s3b6jq2qm6wub%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clpr1bxn800ldeeex763z3yfy%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D). You can try it out. Thank you!

Comment: The documentation you linked says `OUT_DIR` is *"only set during compilation"* - so its probably a fluke that the non-specific case works in the first place. You probably want `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` instead anyway.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks! I don't want to set `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` via cli. I see you can [config it in the toml file ](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildtarget-dir) - `[build] target-dir = 'target'`. Is there a way to extract the value in run time?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` was one that was set rather than one that is provided externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is reported to Cargo on GitHub. Now it should be fixed.
https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/13127#event-11421120844